# How to get root dn in ldap (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ldap

I want to know the root dn in ldap, any command?
Here is what I found in /etc/ldap/slapd.d/cn\=config.ldif

```
dn: cn=config
objectClass: olcGlobal
cn: config
olcArgsFile: /var/run/slapd/slapd.args
olcLogLevel: none
olcPidFile: /var/run/slapd/slapd.pid
olcToolThreads: 1
structuralObjectClass: olcGlobal
entryUUID: 6a0e29d2-7341-1036-810b-5902d64537f7
creatorsName: cn=config
createTimestamp: 20170120094900Z
entryCSN: 20170120094900.675648Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=config
modifyTimestamp: 20170120094900Z
```

dose that mean the root dn is 'cn=config'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many servers expose such parameters as attributes.

You are looking for the **namingContexts** attribute.(Some servers also have a defaultNamingContext and/or configContext.)

You must use "base" as the search scope

These are operational attributes, which have to be explicitly requested by name or by the + wildcard

```
ldapsearch -LLL -h <ldaphost> -b "" -s base +
```

OR if server ask for credentials

```
ldapsearch -LLL -h <ldaphost> -s base -D "bindDN" -w "bindPassword" -b "" +
```

Output

```
dn:
structuralObjectClass: OpenLDAProotDSE
configContext: cn=config
namingContexts: dc=mydomain
namingContexts: dc=mydomain2,dc=myorg
supportedControl: 2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.9
supportedControl: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.473
supportedControl: 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.9.1.1
.
.
.
supportedExtension: 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.20037
supportedExtension: 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.11.1
.
.
supportedFeatures: 1.3.6.1.1.14
supportedFeatures: 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.5.1
.
.
supportedLDAPVersion: 3
supportedSASLMechanisms: LOGIN
supportedSASLMechanisms: PLAIN
entryDN:
subschemaSubentry: cn=Subschema
```